# web.config Transforms: Can You Refer to the Selected Solution Configuration as a Variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, transform, csproj

I've got 5 different Dev environments and 5 different QA environments, named DEV1 thru DEV5 and QA1 thru QA5.  I have different solution configurations and transforms for each.  For each transform, the only thing that changes is the name of a database, which is the same name as the solution configuration.  I'd like to avoid having 10 different transforms.

In the CSPROJ file (MSBuild), you can refer to the solution configuration name using $(Configuration).  Is there any way to refer to the solution configuration name in the same way from a web.config transform file?

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add name="connectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=$(Configuration);User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You probably need a bridge between the two like > https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform .

Comment: @BrandonToms, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to refer to the solution configuration name in the same way from a web.config transform file?

You can add a custom task `ReplaceFileText` into the project file `.csproj` to replace the the name of a database based on the solution configuration.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag , place below scripts:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceFileText" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <OutputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <MatchExpression ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <ReplacementText ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
            File.WriteAllText(
                OutputFilename,
                Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(InputFilename), MatchExpression, ReplacementText)
                );
          ]]></Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithDEV1" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEV1'" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <ReplaceFileText 
      InputFilename="$(ProjectDir)Web.config" 
      OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)Web.config" 
      MatchExpression="Database=Debug" 
      ReplacementText="Database=DEV1" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithDEV2" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEV2'" BeforeTargets="Build">
     ...
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithQA1" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='QA1'" BeforeTargets="Build">
     ...
  </Target>
```

With this task, when you build project, Visual Studio/MSBuild will replace the name of Database in the web.config first.

But there is a another issue, if you build the first time with `configuration=DEV1`, then you build it again with `configuration=DEV2`, that task will fail, because the name of the database was modified to `DEV1` not original `Debug` after the last build.

In order to be able to re-use this task without the need to manually restore the value to "Debug" in the web.config file after each modification, we could back up this file before modification, then add a another task to copy the back up file:

```
  <Target Name="RestoreWebConfigFile" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\BackupWebConfigFile\Web.config" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>
```

So the final custom task should be:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceFileText" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <OutputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <MatchExpression ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <ReplacementText ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Core" />
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
            File.WriteAllText(
                OutputFilename,
                Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(InputFilename), MatchExpression, ReplacementText)
                );
          ]]></Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="RestoreWebConfigFile" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy 
      SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\BackupWebConfigFile\Web.config" 
      DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TransformsWithDEV1" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEV1'" AfterTargets="RestoreWebConfigFile">
    <ReplaceFileText 
      InputFilename="$(ProjectDir)Web.config" 
      OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)Web.config" 
      MatchExpression="Database=Debug" 
      ReplacementText="Database=DEV1" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="TransformsWithDEV2" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DEV2'" AfterTargets="RestoreWebConfigFile">
    <ReplaceFileText 
      InputFilename="$(ProjectDir)Web.config" 
      OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)Web.config" 
      MatchExpression="Database=Debug" 
      ReplacementText="Database=DEV2" />
  </Target>
```

Note: Do not forget copy the `web.config` file to the back-up folder manually before build begins: `BackupWebConfigFile`